# Slided content as absolute

Tags: css, position, slide

Please check this page : www.testnbest.com/test

When we click on " Our services " button the hidden text comes in. But it scrolls down along with the button. I tried to give position: absolute; in hover part of css but not working. It remains hidden in that case. Is it possible to have a css +/ HTML which will show a hidden content when hovered/clicked on the particular button ? Help please..

CSS

```css
#slideout {
 position: fixed;
 top: 320px;
 left: 550px;
 -webkit-transition-duration: .1s;
 -moz-transition-duration: .1s;
 -o-transition-duration: .1s;
 transition-duration: .1s;
}

#slideout_inner {
 position: fixed;
 top: 320px;
 right: -450px;
 -webkit-transition-duration: .1s;
 -moz-transition-duration: .1s;
 -o-transition-duration: .1s;
 transition-duration: .1s;
}

#slideout:hover {
 left: 850px;
}

#slideout:hover #slideout_inner {
 left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="slideout">
  <img src="http://testnbest.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Our-Services.png"/>
  <div id="slideout_inner">
  <ul>
 <li>Wedding events</li>
 <li>Engagements</li>
 <li>House warming</li>
 <li>Birthday parties</li>
 <li>Baptism</li>
 <li>Theme parties</li>
 <li>Festival events</li>
 <li>Official parties</li>
 <li>Travels</li>
 <li>(a/c &amp; non a/c from 4 seater car to 50 seater bus)</li>
 <li>Video/photography</li>
 <li>Caterings</li>
 <li>Auditorium bookings</li>
 <li>Room bookings</li>
 <li>Cottages bookings</li>
 <li>Promotional activities</li>
</ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please include enough code in your question to fully reproduce the error. If your link disappears or dies, then your question is unanswerable/unhelpful to anyone else.

Comment: Done, thanks for suggesting.